# iOS Swift Briefly Display Info

Tags: ios, swift, banner

I want to have some information drop down from the top of a view, stay on the screen for a second or two, and then go back up out of the view.  I have search for displaying notifications and/or banners.  All I get is either push notifications (which I don't need to use) or iAds banners.

I'm working on a barcode scanning app and I want to briefly show the value of the barcode shown without requiring the user to tap on anything.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use notifications and banners, because that might not work: the user can turn them off. In any case this is not a notification of anything, so it's a misuse of notifications.

Just do what you described, yourself: animate a view onto the screen, and then (in the animation's completion handler) use delayed performance to animate the view right back off the screen after a short delay.

Comment: Thanks for sparking my memory!  I've seen it done before with images in a tutorial.  Wasn't hard to make with work with a UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a view which manages its own state (INCOMING, STAY PUT, OUTGOING). This way you can reduce the memory footprint and many other bugs in the process. I coded something for a similar process. Check it [out](https://github.com/ravivooda/AutoDestroyView)

Comment: I checked out your project and it doesn't seem to do anything.  Did I miss something?

Comment: I have to complete the project yet. Just started on it. But I'm thinking of developing a library for the same problem you have. You can look at the source files to help you figure out the solution for auto destroying views.

Comment: Ah, I get it!  I think a library would be very useful for doing that.  If you need someone to test it I would be than happy to.

Comment: Thanks. I will let you know whenever I'm done with it.